# Keep SQLite records in memory cached

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I'm making an Android application with 4 SQLite tables. Each table is related to the other tables (by means of the id row).

I need to select rows a lot in multiple situations while using the applications, so I thought about storing the SELECTed rows in an ArrayList and then getting the rows from that ArrayList for faster access.

Is this a good practice? Would querying the database each time data is needed (a lot, and I will need to query the 4 tables as well each time data is needed) be fast enough and efficient?

It all boils down to one of two choices, do I query the database each time, or query it once and store all the data in ArrayLists?

EDIT:

Here's how complex my data is:
I have 4 related tables, A, B, C and D.

A is my main table, B will contain about 18 rows for each row in A, C will contain about 4 rows for each row in B, and D will contain 4 rows for each row in C.

So for example, if A contains 100 rows, then B will contain 1800 rows, C will contain 7200 and D will contain 28800.

These records need to be accessed a lot.

Comment: Keeping your data in memory will be faster be don't try to keep to much ... the memory on a smartphone is not always enough. And you will need to manage the persistance if you update your data.

Comment: Persistence is not really an issue. The issue is, like you said, memory. If I query all data each time a fragment's onCreateView is called, it might be slow and painful.

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with your data. If this is just to show, you could always look for lazy loading.

Comment: We don't know how complex your queries are, and how fast "fast enough" would be. However, without actual measurements, this smells like premature optimization.

Comment: I'm already lazy loading the data from the database when the activity is first created. The activity's launch mode is singleTask, to make sure that the data is not loaded twice for no reason. The question remains, should I store the data for when other activities need it, or just query it whenever needed.

Comment: @CL. I provided an explanation of how complex the data is.

Comment: reading 28k rows, don't worry about time access.... if your queries and instance creation are well made, you don't need to worry about that since you will never show that much in a screen.

Comment: I agree with @CL. You are probably overthinking this. If you find that it is slow later on you can update your application with some caching.